# Adding a new field to data extracted from a database call

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

As part of a search routine for a specific crop, I'm making two calls to the same database table, merging the results and sending them down the line.  The first call looks for data relating to the searched-for crop (e.g. "beans"). The second call looks for data relating to the crop group of that crop (e.g. legumes).

Data returned from the first call will be more relevant/focused than that from the second call. I want to add an identifier to the respective data sets that reflects this so that I can subsequently sort/present the data on the basis of relevance in my Vue component.

The following code extracts the crop-specific information from the database; how can I add/insert/append a new variable (e.g. "relevance" = 1) to each row in $factsheets before I "array_merge" it with the data returned from the crop-group sql call?

(For sake of simplicitly, I've not included the code that determines the crops.id value from the name of the crop entered by the user.)

```
public function getFactsheets($cropId){
    $factsheets = Factsheet::whereIn('crop_id',$cropId)
      ->join("crop_factsheet as cf","factsheets.id","=","cf.factsheet_id")
      ->join("crops as crops","crops.id","=","cf.crop_id")
      ->select('crops.name','title', 'factsheets.id', 'shortdesc', 'shortimg', 'factsheets.slug')
      ->orderBy('crops.name')
      ->get()->toArray();
      return $factsheets;
    }
```

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give `&` to value so whatever changes will happen to value will directly saved on its address.

```
foreach($factsheets as $key => &$factsheet){
 $factsheet['relevance'] = 1;
}
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66802896a0e98096eb0f53629ead3a3163997d37).

Here is concise explanation of references in [official doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I appreciate the fullness of your answer. Cheers/Tom

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do a foreach

```
foreach($factsheets as $key => $factsheet){
 $factsheet['relevance'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution didn't work "off-the-screen", but modifying its second line to $factsheet[$key]['relevance'] = 1 did the job. Cheers/Tom